# How to update collections automatically in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, triggers

When I update a collection field, I want the mongo to check if it exists in another collection and update it too

I already do this update on my backend, but I wanted to know how I do it by the mongo itself, and also if this is **indicated**

When to update role of person update (**automatically**) function collection

*Person
{
   Office
   Age
   Profession
   Sex 
   FunctionName
}
Function
{
   FunctionName
}*

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used triggers yet, but MongoDB do provide Database triggers that will serve your purpose. 
You can check the link for documentation.
https://docs.mongodb.com/stitch/triggers/database-triggers/